# Firebase web grabar url en database despues de subir archivo al storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase

Tal vez alguien me pueda ayudar con este código estoy tratando de grabar información en el `database` de firebase después de que subo un archivo al `storage` pero no graba solo sube el archivo y lo que deseo es que también guarde el `url` y el nombre del archivo en el `database`

```
window.onload = inicializar;

var fichero;
var storageRef;
var imagenesFBRef;

function inicializar() {
  fichero = document.getElementById("fichero");
  fichero.addEventListener("change",subirImagenAFirebase, false);
  storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  imagenesFBRef=firebase.database().ref().child("imagenesFB");


mostrarImagenesDeFirebase();

}
function mostrarImagenesDeFirebase(){
imagenesFBRef.on("value",function(snapshot){
var datos = snapshot.val();
var result="";
for (var key in datos){
  result +='<img width=200 class="img-thumbnail" src="'+datos[key].url+'"/>';
}
document.getElementById("imagenes-de-firebase").innerHTML=result;
})
}
function subirImagenAFirebase(){
var imagenASubir = fichero.files[0];
// Upload the file and metadata
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + imagenASubir.name).put(imagenASubir);
  document.getElementById("progreso").className="";

  uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  function(snapshot){
var barraProgreso = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
document.getElementById("barra-de-progreso").style.width = barraProgreso + "%";
  }, function(error) {

    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, function() {

    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    var downloadURL= uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;

firebase.database().ref().child('imagenesFB').push({nombre:imagenASubir.name, url:downloadURL});
    crearNodoEnBDFirebase(imagenASubir.name,downloadURL);

    document.getElementById("progreso").className="hidden";

    });

  function crearNodoEnBDFirebase(nombreImagen,downloadURL)  {
//firebase.database().ref('imagenesFB').push({nombre:nombreImagen, url:downloadURL});
imagenesFBRef.push({nombre:nombreImagen, url:downloadURL});

}
}
```

Comment: Jorge por favor formatea correctamente el codigo para que podamos verlo.

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista veo que no estas manejando el caso del upload exitoso, por eso no se ejecuta tu lógica. Según [la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) deberías implementar la subida como:

```
ref.put(archivo).then(function(snapshot) {
  <!-- hacer algo acá -->
});
```

Está medio desordenado el código pero creo que solo estas manejando STATE_CHANGED pero no la subida completa. Podrías confirmar si se llega a ejecutar la seccion de carga en la base de Firebase?

Como comentario te sugiero que veas la sección de [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions), ya que tiene un ejemplo muy similar a lo que querés hacer y te podría ayudar a automatizar esta lógica.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la gentil respuesta, como mencione si sube el archivo en el storage, lo que no logro grabar es el url y el nombre del archivo en el database, conjuntamente, el codigo es el que he estado usando tal vez haciendo unos cambios pero si sube al storage.

Comment: si tuvieras un ejemplo, no necesariamente mi mismo codigo, te agradecería bastante mi estimado

Comment: Entendo que se sube el archivo, pero se llega a ejecutar en algun momento lo que esta debajo de // Handle successful uploads on complete ?

Comment: no justamente eso no se  ejecuta

Comment: prueba implementando la version basica con el then() en mi respuesta. Tu codigo no esta indentado y se me complica revisarlo bien pero imagino que tenes algun parentesis o coma de mas en algun lado y por eso en realidad no tenes implementado el onSuccess